# Remove last 3 letters of div (hidde also in browser page source)

Tags: javascript, html, string, smarty

this is my HTML

```
<div id="remove">Username</div>
```

and this is my JS code

```
function slice() {
var t = document.getElementById("remove");
t.textContent = t.textContent.slice(0, -3);
}
slice();
```

Username load from foreach

```
{foreach from=$last_user item=s}
{$s.date}
{$s.username}
{/foreach}
```

This code working and remove 3 letter but when right click on browser and look at page sources i can see "Username" !
I need remove three letter because of privacy and security .
something like
*** name  or usern ***

Thank for help me !

Comment: you can't change the page source, JS can only change the DOM.

Comment: What's the point of it? Someone could just look at it before the JS runs.

Comment: With JavaScript on client side, you will just be editing the source code received from the server. Using traditional script tags in your HTML code won't allow you to modify the source code itself. Remember the server gives the source code entirely and your browser executes the javascript, but it also allows the user to see the original source code before the execution of your javascript. You need server side code, use PHP or a framework like NextJS with SSR, NuxtJS etc.

Comment: Anything that the user shouldn't see shouldn't be sent to the browser in the first place. Security must be done server-side

Comment: I don't access to server,  data load by smarty engine all i have is TPL file for edit ,  all username load from foreach loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only secure way to make sure the client can't see a particular piece of information is to never send it to the client in the first place. Otherwise, there will always be a way for the client to examine the raw payloads of the network requests and figure out the information they aren't supposed to know.

You'll need to fix this on your backend - either hard-code in

```
<div id="remove">Usern</div>
```

or, for a more dynamic approach, use a template engine (or whatever's generating the HTML) and look up how to change strings with it. For example, in [EJS](https://ejs.co/), if `user` is an object with a `username` property, you could do

```
<div id="remove"><%= user.username.slice(0, -3) %></div>
```

Changing the content only with client-side JavaScript will not be sufficient, if you wish to keep some things truly private.

With Smarty, you can [define a modifier](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/plugins.modifiers.tpl) that takes a string and returns all but the last three characters of it.

```
function smarty_modifier_truncate_three($string)
{
    return substr($string, 0, -3);
}
```

and then in your template, replace

```
{$s.username}
```

with

```
{$s.username|truncate_three}
```

If you want only the first three characters, it's easier because you can use the built-in [`truncate`](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.truncate.tpl).

```
{$s.username|truncate:3}
```

Comment: I updated the code and add foreach item , is there a way load only 3 first letter of username in loop ?

Comment: Show only 3? But your question says (and shows) removing the last 3, not keeping only 3. Which do you want?

Comment: I want only remove three first letter of each username . if username is  (certain) show  (***tain)

Comment: First figure out which approach you want - it's up to you, I can't decide for you. Either use `truncate` to keep only N initial characters, or define a modifier to remove the last N characters.

Comment: Sorry my English not so good , i edited my last comment. if username is (certain) show (***tain)

Comment: truncate_three not working show blank page . but truncate:3 work but only show three dot (...)

Comment: Did you [define the modifier](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/plugins.modifiers.tpl) properly?

Comment: This is the first time you've mentioned that you want to remove characters from the start of the string, which is quite different from both of your previous requests. Please decide on *one*

Comment: All i have need is username show like this => username is (certain) show (***tain).
sorry if i confused you i am so noob here (Also in browser page source )

Comment: Then [define a modifier](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/plugins.modifiers.tpl) that takes the desired substring

Comment: Thank you very much . your help was very helpful and it work like what i want :) :X:X

Answer (score 0):

JS doesn't change the source, it can only change the DOM, so what you can do is to keep the element empty and add a value to it using js, but don't forget that js runs on the client's side so its better here to send the string from the server without the last 3 characters.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).